# RC4 ENCRYPTION algorithm binary conversion

Tags: java, encryption, data-conversion, rc4-cipher

I was referring this [site](http://rc4.online-domain-tools.com/) for RC4 encryption.

there they are getting 2 outputs after encryption one hexadecimal output and other is hexadecimal converted to special characters.
like in the following image

[image]

I was able to replicate the hexadecimal output in java.

My problem is:

- what type of conversion is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the characters as obtained by interpreting the bytes as characters encoded using [ISO-88659-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).